# data structure for adding very large numbers?

Tags: c

how will you add numbers like `1234567890123456789012345678901234567890`, which can't be specified using primitive data types? what kind of data structure will you use?

Comment: "bignum" is a common name for working with numbers larger than processor bitsize - have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c]+bignum

Comment: Kind of just picked one out of a hat, but I'm sure this is a dupe of something. Just check @therefromhere's list.

Answer (score 4):

You will need a C library that implements arbitrary-precision arithmetic. There are many to choose from. One popular choice is [GNU Multi-Precision Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multi-Precision_Library).

Answer (score 2):

Apart from using libraries like [MAPM](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~ringx004/mapm-main.html) and [MPIR](http://mpir.org/) you can try holding them in a double (if precision is not needed), or rollup your own implementation based on arrays.

Google up on [C bignum](http://www.google.com/search?&q=c+bignum) for alternatives.

This is probably [a nice place to start](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~skiena/392/programs/bignum.c).

Comment: Using a double will only work if exact results are not required... otherwise a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to add integers, which your question suggests might be the case, then you could simply use strings and implement single-digit addition with a 2D lookup table.  If your requirements are more complex, then as others have suggested, you need some sort of library for handling big numbers.  Whether you use one of the existing libraries or roll your own is up to you.

Comment: High-performance, high-precision arithmetic is a complicated subject that requires solid background in various fields of mathematics and computer science. So I'd be *very* wary of "roll-your-own"...

Answer (score 2):

I've recently been using [MPFR](http://mpfr.org) - the GNU Multiple Precision Floating-point computations with correct Rounding library. The API is similar in structure to MAPM, which is quite straight forward to use in my experience.

However, if you are only using integers you will probably get better performance from a multiple precision library that has separate integer types (ie MAPM), as MPFR is dedicated to floating point.

Answer (score 1):

For a poor man's bignum addition, you can use C strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *bigadd(const char *a, const char *b) {
    size_t alen = strlen(a);
    size_t blen = strlen(b);
    size_t clen = (alen > blen) ? alen : blen;
    char *c = malloc(clen + 2);
    if (c != NULL) {
        size_t i = clen;
        int carry = 0;
        c[i] = '\0';
        while (i > 0) {
            char digit = (alen ? a[--alen] - '0' : 0) +
                (blen ? b[--blen] - '0' : 0) + carry;
            c[--i] = digit - 10 * (carry = digit > '9');
        }
        if (carry) {
            memmove(c + 1, c, clen + 1);
            c[0] = '1';
        }
    }
    return c;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *a = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "123456890123456890123456890";
    const char *b = argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "2035864230956204598237409822324";
    char *c = bigadd(a, b);
    printf("%s + %s = %s\n", a, b, c);
    free(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use **STACKS**.
Numbers can be stored in the stack by putting digit with highest place value first so that digit at ones place should be on the top of stack. Pop the two stacks and add the digits from stacks with the carry which is initially zero. Push the result in the third stack digit by digit. Repeat till both stacks are empty.